# ¿There is an example of a working example of serial port on ROS Indigo and C++?

Tags: ros, c++, serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.05, and I've found a serial library from William Woodall and John Harrison (https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/) that seem to be exactly what I want. They say that is compatible with ROS, but I'm not finding the way to make it work. A working example with a "hello world" on serial port will be enough for me, because I think my problem is with the dependencies on the CMakeLists.txt.

PD: By now I'm able to compile and run the "serial_example.cpp" included on the package, but that doesn't use ROS, I've tried to make it work but i don't know where's my error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195391/%C2%BFthere-is-an-example-of-a-working-example-of-serial-port-on-ros-indigo-and-c++?/) by [apojomovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20526/apojomovsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at the code of some of the packages that use the serial package. For example:

- http://wiki.ros.org/ax2550
- http://wiki.ros.org/flir_ptu_driver
- http://wiki.ros.org/serial_utils
- http://wiki.ros.org/um6

should give you an idea on how to integrate it in a ROS package.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://github.com/garyservin/serial-example) you have a very simplistic and crude example of a node using the serial package.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apojomovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20526/apojomovsky/) on 2014-10-21**:
thank you very much for taking time to write this example, is exactly what I was looking for! worked like a charm!

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-10-21**:
@Gary Servin Thanks for putting the example together, you beat me to it :)